# How to instanciate a new type created at run time?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have the following code that loads a dll file and creates a new type based on the content of the dll file :

```
    Dim Assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\Test.dll")

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(Assembly.GetName())
    Dim ClassType As Type = Assembly.GetType("Test.ClassTest")

    'This line doesn't compile
    Dim Instance As ClassType
```

The type ClassType is created successfullly but I'm unable to instanciate it or use it in the last line.

Does anyone know how to instanciate a new type created during run time ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
    Dim Assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\Test.dll")

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(Assembly.GetName())
    Dim ClassType As Type = Assembly.GetType("Test.ClassTest")

    Dim Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassType)
```